# How can I float this left?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have this code that all works properly:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>

<!-- Demo date picker from JQuery UI site -->
<div class="demo">
    <p>Start Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</div><!-- End demo -->
<div class="demo">
    <p>End Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker2"></p>
</div><!-- End demo -->
```

And I would like to float this left, however, when I wrap it in a `<div class="left-col"></div>` that has css `float:left;`, the JQuery UI functionality doesn't work anymore.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you make it little more clear? where did you added class `left-col`?

Comment: [works fine for me](http://jsbin.com/ovacim/edit#javascript,html,live), what is wrong with your code then?

Comment: show more code to get better answers

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't provide the `datepicker` jQ script to test this with, we can't figure out how it's not working when floated to the right. My guess is that it's looking for an element but doesn't specify it being in a different div.

Here's it floated left...

http://jsfiddle.net/DMNad/

Answer (score 0):

**Dirty solution:**

Put it in another div and float:left

**Clean solution:**

With no code for me to work from, you need to sort through that class and surrounding classes CSS to see what is conflicting.